# Circles from QGIS into PostGIS

Tags: postgis

If you create a series of circles/buffers in QGIS, what type of geometry do they go into PostGIS as?

Comment: do you need to keep each buffer or can you dissolve the edges? polygon is probably the correct geometry for further spatial analysis.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 1)` will return a POLYGON with 32 sides, or a [**triacontadigon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triacontadigon). If you wan't more or less sides, you can specify `num_seg_quarter_circle` in [ST_Buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) (the default is 8). A series of unioned POLYGONS may result in a MULTIPOLYGON.

If you really need a circle or curved geometry, you can investigate [ST_LineToCurve](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineToCurve.html), however these types of geometry often have poor or limited support, so I recommend avoiding this.

Answer (score 2):

Polygon.

Or.

MultiPolygon.

Depends on the input.